# How to capture the commadline output from an app

Tags: python, ffmpeg

When I ran the command `ffmpeg   -i rtsp://172.19.1.40/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy lala.avi`

The ffmpeg will be continuously printing(refresh) the information `fps` and `bitrate` everyone second.

How could I save those information using Python?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't need python. You can redirect stdout and stderr.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Comment: hi @JayanthKoushik it shows nothing. see my updated post, thanks~

Comment: All the text is on the screen, so of course the file will be empty. The program must be printing to stderr. Redirect that using 2>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can redirect the `stderr` output to a text file like so:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://172.19.1.40/live.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy lala.avi 2> log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use Python, you can use the `subprocess` module with `subprocess.PIPE` and `communicate` like so:

```
import subprocess

cmd = 'ffmpeg', '-i', 'rtsp://172.19.1.40/live.sdp', '-acodec', 'copy', '-vcodec', 'copy', 'lala.avi'
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Then the command's stdout and stderr will be stored in the stdout and stderr variables, respectively.  However, if all you need is to store the output, Drewness's answer is better.